# The plugin flutter_inappwebview requires Android SDK version 33

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter_inappwebview and youtube_player_flutter also in my flutter app.
flutter_inappwebview - 5.4.3+7 and youtube_player_flutter - 8.1.1.
While run the app I am getting like **"The plugin flutter_inappwebview requires Android SDK version 33"**. But after changing the version, Then also its now workin.

I tried changing the version also. It's not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think that try to change the android\app\build.gradle file's:android { compileSdkVersion 33 } and also check that the minSdkVersion, I am not sure about this.

Comment: But I removed the flutter_inappwebview and tried. But still, the error is showing. Is any way to clear the library permanently?

Comment: I think that the problem is not in the flutter_inappwebview some error inside your program. please check